# How to print/display an array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

How to display all items of the array using an alert box?

I have tried : `alert(arr);` and it shows nothing.

**Edit**: I want display this array like php `print_r` function.

```
 output needed like: array["key" => "value", "key" => "value", ...];
```

Comment: `alert(JSON.stringify(arr))` or `alert(arr.join(" "))`

Comment: var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
alert(arr[1]);

Comment: If you're just trying to debug, I would HIGHLY suggest ditching alert and using console.log()

Comment: @flcoder: I'm indeed wondering why `console.log()` hasn't been suggested from the very beginning.

Comment: thanks to all... its working but by using this:  alert(arr.toString()); alert(arr.join(", ")); .... explain ?

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the JavaScript function `toString()`.

```
alert(arr.toString());
```

Comment: Also, instead of alert(), I used console.log() in my answer, but it got removed by an editor. Console.log prints to your js console (usually accessed by pressing ctrl+shift+J in your browser)

Answer (score 3):

To show them in csv, you can use `.join(",")` along with array object:

```
alert(arr.join(", "));
```

for printing individually:

```
$.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
  alert( value );
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As I'm wondering why `console.log()` hasn't been provided as an answer, here it is.

Do:

```
console.log(arr);
```

And open the developper toolbar (<kbd>F12</kbd> on most browsers) and go to the console tab. You should be able to see and expand your array.

Comment: Nevermind, just saw the requirement in OP's question ("*How to display all item of array by **alert** box ?*"). I'll leave my answer though (the OP might not be aware at all of this feature).

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
alert(arr);
for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++){
alert("key "+ i + " and " + "Value is "+arr[i]);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9493ss9u/4/)

To alert each value use this

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = {
  "1": 15,
  "2": 16,
  "3": 17,
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var arrstr="arr[";
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        arrstr+="\""+i+"\" : \""+arr[i]+"\"";   //you can change ":" for "=>", if you like
        if(i!=arr.length-1){//if not the last one ,add "," 
            arrstr+=",";    
        }else{
            arrstr+="]";
        }
    }

    alert(arrstr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
        console.log(teams[i]);
           
}
```

worked for me.

Comment: Not sure if this is a "thanks" or an attempt at an answer. It doesn't actually answer the original problem, as it doesn't use `alert()` or provide the format that the OP asked for.

Comment: @jmoerdyk Looks legit (however, not particularly good) to me. I think the usage of `console.log()` comes from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472559/how-to-print-display-an-array-in-jquery/75617533#comment52806581_32472559) on the question.